# How to plot multiple leveled plots in R

Tags: r, plot

I'm working my way through [AppliedPredictiveModeling](https://github.com/topepo/APM_Exercises/blob/master/Ch_07.pdf) and encountered a plot with no description as to how it functions. The code to generate the data is:

```
svmParam2 <- expand.grid(eps = c(.01, 0.05, .1, .5 ), costs= 2^c(-2, 0, 2, 8),
                     sigma = as.vector(sigest(y~x, data=sinData, frac=.75)))

for (i in 1:nrow(svmParam2)){
   rbfSVM<-ksvm(x=x, y=y, data=sinData,
           kernel="rbfdot",
           kpar=list(sigma=svmParam2$sigma[i]),
           C=svmParam2$costs[i],
           epsilon=svmParam2$eps[i])

   tmp <- data.frame(x=dataGrid$x,
                y=predict(rbfSVM, newdata=dataGrid),
                eps=paste("epsilon:", format(svmParam2$eps)[i]),
                costs=paste("cost:", (svmParam2$costs)[i]),
                sigma=paste("sigma:", format(svmParam2$sigma, digits=2)[i]))
  svmPred2 <- if(i==1) tmp else rbind(tmp, svmPred2)
}
svmPred2$costs <- factor(svmPred2$costs, levels = rev(levels(svmPred2$costs)))
svmPred2$sigma <- factor(svmPred2$sigma, levels = rev(levels(svmPred2$sigma)))
```

and the plots look like this: [What I want to replicate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUrq2.png)

Each plot is a regular x, y plot with four different curves, one for each value of sigma, there are 16 different plots total, with a different cost value for each column, and a different epsilon value for each row.

Comment: Nothing [`facet_wrap`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) can't handle.

Comment: From the looks of your example plot, they're using lattice graphs. Try creating one of the plots (for one cost value), then use a formula to replicate that plot across all costs using lattice. Or you could go a ggplot route and use facet_wrap.

Comment: What is on the `x` axis?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, the x axis is a vector with 100 values between 2 and 10. 
I believe the plots are indeed made using lattice, do you have any example code on how that might be done with a data frame of my format? I've been taking some shots at it with no success.

Comment: @Marcus Grass the question is clear, however I do not understand what the x axis maps - the 100 values represent what exactly? If you could explain it, I would be glad to post code for both lattice and ggplot. The y axis is accuracy, the colors and facets are also obvious but what is the x axis?

Comment: @missuse Oh, I'm using SVM to approximate a sine-curve between the values of 2 and 10, here are the definitions:     
    `x <- runif(100, min=2, max=10)
       y <- sin(x)+rnorm(length(x))*.25
       sinData <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)`

The code is lifted from the github link (AppliedPredictiveModeling)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one approach would be to use ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(svmPred2)+
   geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y, color = sigma))+
   facet_grid(eps ~ costs) +
   theme_bw()
```

[image]

and with lattice:

```
library(lattice)
library(latticeExtra)

useOuterStrips(strip=strip.custom(bg = "skyblue"), 
               strip.left=strip.custom(bg = "skyblue"), 
               xyplot(y~x |costs *eps,
                      data = svmPred2,
                      type = 'l',
                      groups = sigma,
                      col = c("red","blue","green"),
                      auto.key = list(columns = 3)))
```

[image]

data:

```
library(kernlab)

x <- runif(100, min=2, max=10)
y <- sin(x)+rnorm(length(x))*.25
sinData <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
dataGrid <- data.frame(x = seq(2, 10, length = 100))

svmParam2 <- expand.grid(eps = c(.01, 0.05, .1, .5 ), costs= 2^c(-2, 0, 2, 8),
                         sigma = as.vector(sigest(y~x, data=sinData, frac=.75)))

svmPred2 <- data.frame()
for (i in 1:nrow(svmParam2)){
  rbfSVM<-ksvm(x=x, y=y, data=sinData,
               kernel="rbfdot",
               kpar=list(sigma=svmParam2$sigma[i]),
               C=svmParam2$costs[i],
               epsilon=svmParam2$eps[i])

  tmp <- data.frame(x=dataGrid$x,
                    y=predict(rbfSVM, newdata=dataGrid),
                    eps=paste("epsilon:", format(svmParam2$eps)[i]),
                    costs=paste("cost:", (svmParam2$costs)[i]),
                    sigma=paste("sigma:", format(svmParam2$sigma, digits=2)[i]))
  svmPred2 <- if(i==1) tmp else rbind(tmp, svmPred2)
}
svmPred2$costs <- factor(svmPred2$costs, levels = rev(levels(svmPred2$costs)))
svmPred2$sigma <- factor(svmPred2$sigma, levels = rev(levels(svmPred2$sigma)))
```